# Shunt both op-amp input terminals individually

Tags: operational-amplifier, resistors, shunt, inverting-amplifier

[image]

I'm working on a lab project for my class. My manual says that I need to **shunt both OPAMP input terminals individually with resistors Rx = 1kΩ.**

I'm not sure what that means.

Where should I put the additional Rx resistors?

Comment: It means to connect them in parallel with the op-amp, probably. Between the terminal and ground. Probably.

Comment: What is the goal of the lab project?